# Gremlin: can't sort edges and return vertices

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop-frames

I'm trying to write a Gremlin query to traverse a graph using Tinkerpop Frames.

Here is the code I have:

```
@GremlinGroovy("it"
            + ".outE"
            + ".filter{it.label=='usedwith'}"
            + ".sort{-it.weight}"
            + ".toList()"
            + ".reverse()"
            + "[start, 'start+size']"
            +"._"
            + ".inV")
public Iterable<Ingredient> getMostUsedWith(@GremlinParam("start") int start, 
                                            @GremlinParam("size") int size);
```

I basically want to get all edges from my current vertex with type 'usedwith', sort them based on weight attribute descendingly and then get a page from the list of vertices that these edges are pointing at.

Sadly this code doesn't work and throws a lot of errors. Can you revise this?

Comment: 1) Why do you `revese` the list instead of sort it ascending? 2) What is the purpose of `[start, 'start+size']`? A slice of the list from start to (start + size) or a list of length 2 with elements at start and (start + size)? This part is not included in your description (How do you prevent OutOfBoundExceptions?).

Comment: I think Frames handles the out of bound. It works ok here. You got all of what I intended to do right in your answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could write your query as:

```
it.outE('usedwith').order{it.b.weight <=> it.a.weight}.inV[start..(start + size)]
```

Comment: Thanks. Obviously I did some silly mistakes. Do you recommend any tutorials on Gremlin?

Comment: Hmm … I think the best thing to do is to play around with the various commands on the toy graph (https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Property-Graph-Model) in the REPL. Type `g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()` in the gremlin shell and run the example commands from the API page (http://gremlindocs.com). Be aware that this page is for gremlin 2 and many things in the dsl changed with tinkerpop 3, afaik. Good luck and have fun!

Comment: For your problem you could for instance run on the toy graph: `g.v(1).outE('knows').order{it.b.weight <=> it.a.weight}.inV[0..1]`